# Нативные игры на Linux запускаются и работают отлично, а игры запущенные через Wine крашат пк через 10-15 минут игры

Tags: linux, amd, wine

Neofetch:

```
OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
Host: X99 Kernel: 6.7.5-zen1-1-zen 
Uptime: 13 mins Packages: 903 (pacman), 10 (flatpak) 
Shell: bash 5.2.26 
Resolution: 1600x900 
DE: Plasma 5.27.10 WM: kwin 
Theme: [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: [Plasma], breeze-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2650 v4 (24) @ 2.900GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon HD 7750/8740 / R7 250E 
Memory: 3613MiB / 15827MiB
```

Версия Wine: wine-tkg-staging-fsync-git 9.2.r3.g29b947b8-327
Драйвер видеокарты: amdgpu

При краше перестает работать даже кнопка экстренной перезагрузки, мне кажется что это каким то образом отрубается процессор

Comment: Поставь Винду и играй. Там на коробке написано "games for windows"

Comment: @eri хочу остаться на линуксе

Comment: Может на виндовс тоже зависает? Проверь

Comment: @eri Нет, это только на линуксе

Comment: Wine как любая программа выполняемая не под рутом не может в принципе крешить систему без серьезной на то причины, как то наличие аппаратных проблем, исчерпание ресурсов (при утечках памяти например), ошибках в системном програмнои обеспечении. Если вам интересно решить эту задачу нужно начинать с анализа логов самой системы и отбрасывать причины расставив их в порядке вероятности.